# How to get new (2020) React Developer Tools to show elements as old version did?

Tags: reactjs

I'm working through a React video from 2019 and their React Developer Tools extension (in Safari) looks like this:

[image]

However, my React Developer Tools in both Firefox and Chrome extensions look like this:

[image]

One can see here that the presenter in the video is getting much more information about the React component than I am getting:

[image]

**Is there a way to see the elements as in the old version of the extension? Or does one have to use React Developer Tools in a different way now?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inline props in tree have been removed for better performances, however, you can still get an element's details by selecting it:

[image]

Also, for a more detailed DOM tree view, it can be displayed by clicking on the eye icon on the top-right which says "Inspect the matching DOM element".

Another thing I noticed is that selecting a component automatically make the `$r` variable refers to it.

Comment: Thanks, and I noticed clicking the `<>` icon shows the code for that section, which could be useful.

What do you mean by the `$r` variable?

Comment: @EdwardTanguay `$r` lets you work with the instance of the selected component, for example, for a component named `MyComp` you will be able to access its data and log them in the console by doing `$r.state`, `$r.props` or simply `$r` for much more details.